# A working nodeJS module to validate locally a sitemap.xml

Tags: node.js, sitemap

I've been looking around and none of the npm modules available seem to validate a *local existing* sitemap.xml! I mean validation like [this online tool](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/index.php?op=validate-xml-sitemap).

How can I validate a `sitemap.xml` locally in nodeJS?

Comment: What do you mean by validate a sitemap.xml? If you want to validate the XML structure you can do it by using a XSD (the following seems the official: https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd) and their is npm modules to do this kind of validation.

Comment: @Thom I mean like this online tool: https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/index.php?op=validate-xml-sitemap. Which npm modules? The ones I've seen are simply deprecated. I'm not that versed in XML and the info in Google is scarce.

Comment: I pretty sure that this tool do mostly an XSD validation. You can use module like [libxml-xsd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libxml-xsd) do check your sitemap.xml

Comment: @Thom can you post a short snippet such that I can tag it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You validate your `sitemap.xml` file using an XSD. In your case you want to use the following [sitemap.xsd](https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd).

Then use a module to validate an XML file against an XSD you can use for example [`libxml-xsd`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libxml-xsd).

```
var xsd = require('libxml-xsd');

xsd.parseFile(schemaPath, function(err, schema){
  schema.validate(documentString, function(err, validationErrors){
    // err contains any technical error
    // validationError is an array, null if the validation is ok
  });  
});
```

In this snippet (from `libxml-xsd`doc) `schemaPath`is the path to your XSD file and `documentString` is a string with your `sitemap.xml` content.